# How do I point a domain to an Ubuntu VPS?

Tags: dns, nginx, vps

I've recently purchased a VPS hosting (rackspace) and want to configure a domain for this account. I've configured nginx and other stuff to run Ruby on Rails on it. And everything works perfectly when I reach it by its ip. I've changed the domain DNS servers at my domain registrant to point to my hosting. I've been waiting for 48+ hours but still no luck. Maybe I should add some configuration on the server side? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the domain correctly resolve to the VPS's IP?  `host domain.tld`, replacing `domain.tld` with the actual domain, will give you the answer for that.  If that resolves, then it's probably a config issue and I can help with that.

Comment: Should I run this command via terminal? `host domain.ltd`?

Comment: If yes, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: replace `domain.tld` with your actual domain though when you run the command via the terminal.  If you don't have one, then that's the first thing you need to go  get.

Comment: I understood, I've replaced and run this command via terminal and it returned nothing.

Comment: I don't want to ask a billion questions via comments, can you stop by [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9065/discussion-on-link-a-domain-to-ubuntu-vps) to discuss this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We discussed this [in a chat room here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9065/discussion-on-link-a-domain-to-ubuntu-vps), however this is the brief summary:

1. Make sure you have a domain name.
2. Make sure that the domain points to your provider's name servers.
3. Make sure that an `A` record exists (for IPv4) in the provider's name servers which points your domain to the correct IP for your VPS.  If it's an IPv6 address, use an `AAAA` record.
4. Make sure that nginx has a `server_name` line in the configuration for the `server {` block which has the domain name in it.

And you're done.

To add additional sites in nginx, make additional `server {` blocks in the configuration file with the relevant configuration data, after making sure the domain points to the IP address for your server, and that the `server_name` lines contain the domain name(s) in that line for each relevant site root directory on the server.